# Tensorflow Lite sample : Wifi camera support?

Tags: android, ios, tensorflow, wifi-direct, tensorflow-lite

I'd like to use the [Tensorflow Lite sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite) with a Wifi camera on iOS/Android.
Is this currently supported ?

Note : The mobile device would act as a Wifi Hotspot where the camera would live stream through [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol).

If not supported, could I open a feature request on GitHub ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I'm totally wrong about this sample using the camera feed. It uses a simple image. Sorry about that.

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that I think this question might be off-topic for SO (since it's not about coding itself), TF-Lite is just an inference engine. You feed it images, it gives out the graph's results. The _source_ of those images is not TF-Lite's concern so, as long as you can grab images from a Wifi camera on iOS/Android, yes, you can use that image with TF-Lite

Comment: it is about coding. If you try the sample you'd see that the images are coming from the device camera. I changed the question's title.

Comment: That's a sample showing how to use TF-Lite, which they do. You should look up how to get images from the camera you want to use (and that's completely unrelated to TF-Lite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow lite receives an image and produces a prediction for it. it is completely agnostic to the device that captures the image that you feed into it.

Comment: The title of my question was unclear. My question is about the sample, not Tensorflow itself.